# Word for a car accessory that is standard trim, or a low-cost option

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm looking for a word or two that covers in a vehicle all-round cameras, built-in sonar and radar, etc that may be in the base price or in a low-cost package, and all mount unobtrusively into pre-allocated mountings, but excludes exotic items like LIDAR that sits on the roof of the car and would only be a third-party or specialised purchase. "Off-the-shelf" is close, I think, but is there something better?

The sample heading I am trying to fix currently reads:

> Using only in-vehicle conventional sensing devices

"in-vehicle conventional" are the words I want to replace. This is for a formal poster.

Answer (score 1):

How about base-model?
*Using only base-model sensing devices.*

Base model definition:

> A basic version of a product, to which alterations, additions, and enhancements can be made as desired; specifically the standard (and usually cheapest) model of a motor vehicle.

Comment: "Base model" isn't quite right - sonar and radar aren't always base-model equipment, for instance.

Comment: So you're looking for something that's a cheaper model but isn't the base one? Budget model? Just budget? Cheaper model? Not quite sure now what word you mean.

Comment: I'd just say what they are. If you mean **all-around cameras** say that. The audience isn't going to know what is conventional or base model or not, as that varies widely by manufacturer.

Comment: *Budget* is commonly used of new products (e.g. budget phone) if you think *cheap* is too vague; if it's an old product then *legacy* might be better. But the question isn't very clear.